# How to select a single dictionary value from user input key with a loop

Tags: python-3.x

Pasting my code below.

I'm trying to create a text based game. In this portion I want my user to make a selection from the given items. If their selection is correct then they move out of the puzzle. If incorrect then they are to be prompted to try again.

I understand a list can be used to do this, but I feel less code can be used using a dictionary,and quality of life much better than:

```
challenge_1_response = input("> ").lower()
challenge_1_answers = ["magnifying glass", "beaker", "serrated knife", "callendar"]
if challenge_1_response == "magnifying glass":
    print("If I look hard enough, I can see...")
elif challenge_1_response == "beaker":
    print("If I smash that Beaker I can use the shard to cut loose")
elif challenge_1_response == "serrated knife":
    print("You've cut loose")
elif challenge_1_response == "callendar":
    print("Oh no. Has it really been that long?")
while challenge_1_response not in challenge_1_answers:
    print("I can only choose what's in front of me")
    challenge_1_response = input("> ").lower()
        if challenge_1_response == "magnifying glass":
        print("If I look hard enough, I can see...")
        elif challenge_1_response == "beaker":
            print("If I smash that Beaker I can use the shard to cut loose")
        elif challenge_1_response == "serrated knife":
            print("You've cut loose")
        elif challenge_1_response == "callendar":
            print("Oh no. Has it really been that long?")
```

Please see that this tidbit segment was just to be used as an example. The idea is that with a dictionary all possible keys along with their follow up message will be in a single variable as opposed to writing several lines of code if the same information was in a list. The other side to this is if I wanted to go back and make additions, or edit information, going back to a dictionary is easier.

I've gotten my code to

```
import sys
import time
import os

os.system("clear")

def puzzle_1():
    challenge_1_scene = "The buckles are strapped tightly, it'll be tough prying myself loose. The lights above me are quite bright, it's painful to keep my eyes open. But...I can see there's a table next to me, and on it: [ Magnifying Glass, Beaker, Serrated Knife, Callendar ] Maybe I can use one of them to get out\n"
    for character in challenge_1_scene:
            sys.stdout.write(character)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.05)
    challenge_1_response = input("> ").lower()        
    challenge_1_answers = {
        "magnifying glass": "If I look hard enough, I can see...",
        "beaker": "If I smash that Beaker I can use the shard to cut loose",
        "serrated knife": "You've cut loose",
        "callendar": "Oh no. Has it really been that long?",
    }
    if challenge_1_response in challenge_1_answers[challenge_1_response]:
        print(challenge_1_answers[challenge_1_response])
    while challenge_1_response not in challenge_1_answers[challenge_1_response]
        print("I can only choose what's in front of me")
        challenge_1_response = input("> ").lower()
        if challenge_1_response in challenge_1_answers[challenge_1_response]:
            print(challenge_1_answers[challenge_1_response])
        
        
puzzle_1()
```

Can this be done with a dictionary?

Comment: What error are you getting with the current code?

Comment: If I choose the correct response first I won't enter the loop. When typing the wrong answer I enter the loop. It then prompts me for a selection 4 times (along with the wrong response print statement), then takes me out on my next prompt. While in the loop even if I choose the correct answer it'll give me the wrong response print statement.

There's no error message that comes up. It's just not functioning as I want it to.

Comment: Store this in a variable and see what the data is `challenge_1_answers[challenge_1_response]`. Are your if statements in the loop doing what you want? Does the `in` keyword make sense there? Are you really trying to see if that key exists in the dictionary? How would you check that? Is a non-existent key null?

Comment: Okkkkkkk. I found my answer. I have no clue why I didn't do it before this whole time...........

Answer (score 0):

```
challenge_1_response = input("> ").lower()
challenge_1_answers = {
    "magnifying glass": "If I look hard enough, I can see...",
    "beaker": "If I smash that Beaker I can use the shard to cut loose",
    "serrated knife": "You've cut loose",
    "callendar": "Oh no. Has it really been that long?",
    }
if challenge_1_response in challenge_1_answers:
    print(challenge_1_answers[challenge_1_response])
while challenge_1_response not in challenge_1_answers:
    print("I can only choose what's in front of me")
    challenge_1_response = input("> ").lower()
    if challenge_1_response in challenge_1_answers:
        print(challenge_1_answers[challenge_1_response])
```

I've seriously been on this all day. I even looped as to the different attempts I was trying. Long story short, I took out the dictionaries index value and just kept the dictionary itself in the "in" statement. When getting to the print statement I can call the user inputted key for its respective value. During the while loop I need it to look for that same statement, otherwise go for a loop.

I swore I tried this before, but must have been doing something wrong. Anyway this works :)

I understand it needs to be touched up, but I was mostly looking for it to function the way I wanted to. Getting it right is a breeze after that.